# JavaScript выбрать случайное только числовое значение в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, как можно выбрать случайное значение в массиве вида:

```
var arr = [0, true, 1, false, 56, 'что', 'здесь', 'происходит', 100];
```

учитывая только числа и игнорируя строковые и boolean-значения и вывести порядковый номер этого значения. Например, в данном массиве перебрать только 0, 1, 56, 100, выбрать случайное число (допустим 56) и вывести его порядковый номер (4). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Класс, а что Вы сделали для поимки ответа?

Comment: @Other Дошел до вот этого момента Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length); Но как выбрать только числа ума не приложу. Есть .isNumeric(); но как его использовать в этом коде я не нахожу решения.

Comment: Так Ваше решение нужно поместить в вопрос. На данный момент это выглядит как задание на бирже, только за так.

Answer (score 3):

**Алгоритм, который работает с линейной скоростью - O(n):**

```js
var arr = [0, true, 1, false, 56, 'что', 'здесь', 'происходит', 100];

var onlyNumIndex = arr.reduce(function(p,c,i){
  // проверка на число, если да - оставляем его индекс
  return (typeof c === 'number' && isFinite(c) ? p.push(i) : 0, p);
}, []); // массив, который содержит только индексы

// выбираем случайный индекс и показываем его
var randIndex = onlyNumIndex[Math.floor(Math.random() * onlyNumIndex.length)];

alert(randIndex);
```

**Алгоритм который работает с минимальным временем O(1) и максимальным ~O(n):**

Суть его заключается в том, чтобы тыкать:D случайно в массив, и с x попытки мы попадем на число(чем больше концентрация чисел - тем лучше)

```js
var arr = [0, true, 1, false, 56, 'что', 'здесь', 'происходит', 100];

var randIndex;
while(randIndex == undefined) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  var num = arr[rand];
  if(typeof num === 'number' && isFinite(num)) randIndex = rand;
}

alert(randIndex);
```

Сравнение времени работы алгоритмов(test1 - метод O(n), test2 - метод от O(1) до ~O(n)): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Итого:**
второй метод с рандомным тыком - быстрее)))

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = [];
var array = [1, 2, "das"];

array.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(item)) && isFinite(item))
    result.push(item)
});
console.log(result);
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (result.length));
console.log(array.indexOf(result[randomIndex]));
```

Кладем в массив result, все элементы исходного массива, являющиеся числами. 
Выбираем из массива чисел случайное.
Выводим индекс этого числа в исходном массиве.

Для определения того, что элемент массива является числом используем выражение вида:

```
!isNaN(parseFloat(item)) && isFinite(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать немного хитрее.

Чтобы проверить, что элемент число, сделаем так:

```
function isNumber(value) {
    return typeof value === 'number' && Number.isFinite(value)
}
```

1. Узнаем, что данный объект - численный объект
2. Узнаем, что объект не `Infinity` и не `NaN`

Затем необходимо узнать индексы чисел, для этого создадим пустой массив и будем добавлять в него индексы элементов, на месте которых число:

```
let buffer = [];
for (let i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; ++i) {
    isNumber(array[i]) && buffer.push(i);
}
```

1. Создаем буфер для индексов
2. Проходим по всем элементам массива
3. Если элемент число, тогда, бинго, добавляем его индекс в массив

Далее остается только получить случайный индекс:

```
function getRandomNumberIndex(buffer) {
    return buffer[Math.floor(Math.random() * buffer.length)];
}
```

1. Получаем случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до length - 1
2. Берем элемент под этим индексом

Итого у нас получается:

1. Поиск чисел за O(n)
2. Выбор индекса за O(1)